# swfupload init with addOnloadEvent

Tags: swfupload, onload-event

i am using an addOnloadEvent(initSwfUpload) function to init the
swfupload.

Here are my functions

```
function addOnloadEvent(fnc){
  if ( typeof window.addEventListener != "undefined" )
    window.addEventListener( "load", fnc, false );
  else if ( typeof window.attachEvent != "undefined" ) {
    window.attachEvent( "onload", fnc );
  }
  else {
    if ( window.onload != null ) {
      var oldOnload = window.onload;
      window.onload = function ( e ) {
        oldOnload( e );
        window[fnc]();
      };
    }
    else
      window.onload = fnc;
  }

}

function initSwfUpload()
{
         var swf = new SWFUpload({
                                // Backend Settings
                                upload_url: "../../../upload.php",
                                ...
                                ....
        })

}
```

Its working fine but now i need to use the addPostParam(name, value)
but swf is not available.

Here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        addOnloadEvent(initSwfUpload);
        swf.addPostParam('c','1');
</script>
```

I get the message swf is undefined.

Is possible using the addOnloadEvent approach to achieve the above.

For several reasons i dont want ro use the classic swfupload init

```
var swfu;
window.onload = function () {
 swfu = new SWFUpload({
  .......
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to define swfu object outside function first to make it global.

```
function addOnloadEvent(fnc){
  if ( typeof window.addEventListener != "undefined" )
    window.addEventListener( "load", fnc, false );
  else if ( typeof window.attachEvent != "undefined" ) {
    window.attachEvent( "onload", fnc );
  }
  else {
    if ( window.onload != null ) {
      var oldOnload = window.onload;
      window.onload = function ( e ) {
        oldOnload( e );
        window[fnc]();
      };
    }
    else
      window.onload = fnc;
  }

}

var swf;

function initSwfUpload()
{
         swf = new SWFUpload({
                                // Backend Settings
                                upload_url: "../../../upload.php",
                                ...
                                ....
        })

}
```

Then you can use this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        addOnloadEvent(initSwfUpload);
        swf.addPostParam('c','1');
</script>
```